# Why coordinate indicate middle of path constructed with controls rather then the start point

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

Consider this example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,1)..controls +(2,4) and +(-2,-6)..(4,0)
..controls  +(2,6) and +(-2,-6.5)..(8,0)coordinate[pos=0](A);

\draw[<-](A)--+(0,2)node[above]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Although I have mentioned `pos=0` in `coordinate[pos=0](A)`! look like the path is divided into two paths ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the defined behaviour. From section 17.8 Placing Nodes on a Line or Curve Explicitly:

[image]

*Previous coordinate* in your case is `(4,0)` and *current point* is `(8,0)`, therefore `pos=0` is at `(4,0)`.

Following example shows the same case with a path built with two segments:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (3,1) -- (4,5) coordinate[pos=0] (A) coordinate[pos=0.5] (B) coordinate[pos=.75] (C);

\path (A) node {A};
\path (B)node {B};
\path (C)node {C};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Technically these are two separate paths, but you can do

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,1)..controls +(2,4) and +(-2,-6)..(4,0) coordinate[pos=0](A)
..controls  +(2,6) and +(-2,-6.5)..(8,0);

\draw[<-](A)--+(0,2)node[above]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```